# fb.login question from a novice - how to implement display=touch?

Tags: jquery, mobile, oauth, facebook

I'm developing for mobile, I have a simple app that launches a page in webview (no browser toolbar, address bar, etc.). Since this browser config can't really handle popup windows, how can I implement it not to launch a popup but a simple url call for oauth? And also I'd like to use the display="touch" feature in the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if ( window.FB ) {
    FB.init({appId: '123456789000000',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true});
    $( 'html' ).attr( 'xmlns:og', 'http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/' );
    $( 'html' ).attr( 'xmlns:fb', 'http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' );
}
});

function fbc_login() {
    if ( window.FB ) {
        FB.login( function( response ) {
            if ( response.session ) {
                window.location = 'http://www.mobii.hu/';
                }
            }, 
            { perms: 'email' 
            });
    }
};
function fbc_logout() {
    if ( window.FB ) {
        FB.logout( function( response ) {
            window.location = 'http://www.mobii.hu/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=logout&Itemid=2';
            });
        }
    };
function fbc_unjoin() {
    if ( window.FB ) {
        if ( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to unjoin http://www.mobii.hu?' ) ) {
        FB.api({
            method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function( response ) {window.location = 'http://www.mobii.hu/';});
        }
    }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ( window.FB ) { 
        FB.logout( function( response ) {} ); 
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for asking this so well! :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, display="touch" doesn't work properly using the JS SDK. The best plan of attack here is a combination of using the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) in harmony with the JavaScript SDK. The idea is to use the PHP SDK's built-in method getLoginUrl() to generate a login URL based on your application's configuration, requested permissions, etc. then pass that URL to your JavaScript function.

The PHP:

```
<?php
include('facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET
));

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'email', // Non-OAuth 2.0 apps.
    /* 'scope' => 'email', */ // OAuth 2.0 apps.
    'display' => 'touch'
));
?>
```

And your fbc_login() function should simply be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fbc_login() {
        document.location='<?php print $loginUrl; ?>';
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You just saved me about 45 minutes of my life. Respect.